# Ember find existing hasMany models

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

How can I get (or rather check for the existence of) the sub-model objects that belong to a parent model in Ember-Data (v1.13.15) without throwing errors?

I have associated models looking like this:

```
// models/parent.js
...
export default DS.Model.extend({
    children: DS.hasMany('child', {async:true, inverse:'parent'}),
...
});


// models/child.js
...
export default DS.Model.extend({
    parent: DS.belongsTo('parent', {async:true, inverse:'children'}),
....
});
```

In my route's model hook I'm trying to check if I have any children already associated with my parent (parent btw is also a submodel of a hasMany/belongsTo of a 'family' model...). If I haven't added any children yet, I need to create some and associate them to the parent object, but when I do something like:

```
parent.get('children').then(function(children){
    // would be nice to get in here and maybe have children.length == 0
});
```

I get *`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`*. Similarly can't call `parent.get('children').get('length')`. `this.store.findAll('child').then...` also seems to error out.

Is it not possible to get an empty array or do I have to use some dirty catch to figure out if I have any submodels? I'm pretty inexperienced with Ember so any pointers or help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: shouldn't `parent.get('children.length')` do what you need? or `parent.get('children').get('length');`

Comment: those similarly throw the same error.

Comment: correction: using the promise syntax of `.then` I get the error. I use `.then` as I wanted to be sure the length was really that, and not just an unfulfilled promise. Grabbing the length directly as you mentioned returns `undefined`, which I suppose would work but still wouldn't be certain it wasn't just the promise unfulfilled. thanks though, i may just go with checking for `undefined`.